# Can't get the Go Guestbook demo for Google App Engine Managed VM to run locally

Tags: google-app-engine, go

I'm following the instructions on this page: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/managed-vms/ trying to get the example guestbook demo shown here to work: https://github.com/golang/appengine/tree/master/demos/guestbook

The demo works when deployed, but not when run locally. Running locally gives following error in the browser when hitting localhost:8080: `service bridge HTTP failed: Post http://10.0.2.2:41019/rpc_http: dial tcp 10.0.2.2:41019: i/o timeout`

The error occurs when trying to access the datastore. The debug statement is `DEBUG: Container: f18ca4d19536: 2014/12/31 03:08:22 ERROR: GetAll: service bridge HTTP failed: Post http://10.0.2.2:36788/rpc_http: dial tcp 10.0.2.2:36788: i/o timeout` which is generated when the query.GetAll function fails.

Here are the statements I used to prepare to run the guestbook demo:

```
gcloud config set project <project name>
gcloud components update app
gcloud components update gae-go
goapp get google.golang.org/appengine
gcloud preview app setup-managed-vms
remove the "application: vm-guestbook" line from app.yaml
add "apt-get update" to the generated Dockerfile
gcloud preview app run app.yaml
```

Any ideas what's wrong?  If I deploy the app using `gcloud preview app deploy app.yaml` it works fine. But I'd really like to figure out how to run Managed VM apps locally.

I should mention that I'm able to run the helloworld demo locally. The difference is the helloworld demo doesn't access the datastore.  Also, I'm running on Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that your configuration is not currently supported.
We currently require the use of boot2docker and VirtualBox even on Linux.